# How to vertically overflow HTML ul list past form and div tags?

Tags: html, css

I am building my first search bar/engine and I came across this problem. The problem is that the search results which are an unordered list is only showing the last list element instead of showing all the list elements. I want the list to overflow or pass the parent `<form>` and `<div>` tags and I tried CSS overflow, which did not work.

Edit:

Link to webpage: http://techteach.us/Web2020/ZWeiJian/WCP/Labs/Lab_01/Lab_1.html

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="sideBtn">

                <a href="Lab_1.html">Home</a>
                <a href="Lb1Labs.html">Labs</a>
                <a href="Lb1Projects.html">Projects</a>
                <a href="https://qwfepfp.blogspot.com/2019/09/blog-intromy-bio-2.html">Blogger</a>
                <a href="http://techteach.us/index.html">Techteach.us</a>
                <a href="http://techteach.us/Web2020/">Parent Directory</a>

                <!--Basic Search Bar.-->
                <form id="srchFrm">
                    <input id="srchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>


                <ul id="srchRslts">
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">!</a></li>
                </ul>

                </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.sideBtn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sideBtn a{
  height: 32px;
  color: #000000;
}

.sideBtn a:hover {
    background-color: #22B0FF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/**Search bar 
Credit goes to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_searchbar3
**/
#srchFrm {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: thin;
}

#srchFrm button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#srchRslts {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

#srchRslts li a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 73.425%;
    height: auto;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0.1874px;
    border: 0.25px solid #dbdbdb;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

#srchRslts li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Comment: They should overflow by default, am I missing anything [in this pen](https://codepen.io/Libruhh/pen/abbMyeK)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the position: absolute on `#srchRslts li a` then set height and overflow: auto on `#srchRslts`.

See code below:

```css
.sideBtn {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}

.sideBtn a{
  height: 32px;
  color: #000000;
}

.sideBtn a:hover {
    background-color: #22B0FF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/**Search bar 
Credit goes to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_searchbar3
**/
#srchFrm {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 6px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: thin;
}

#srchFrm button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: thin;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#srchRslts {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#srchRslts li a {
    display: block;
/*     position: absolute; */
    width: 73.425%;
    height: auto;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0.1874px;
    border: 0.25px solid #dbdbdb;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

#srchRslts li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<div class="sideBtn">

                <a href="Lab_1.html">Home</a>
                <a href="Lb1Labs.html">Labs</a>
                <a href="Lb1Projects.html">Projects</a>
                <a href="https://qwfepfp.blogspot.com/2019/09/blog-intromy-bio-2.html">Blogger</a>
                <a href="http://techteach.us/index.html">Techteach.us</a>
                <a href="http://techteach.us/Web2020/">Parent Directory</a>

                <!--Basic Search Bar.-->
                <form id="srchFrm">
                    <input id="srchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>


                <ul id="srchRslts">
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">!</a></li>
                </ul>

                </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried doing that and the lists do not overflow the parent div though.

Comment: okay, please take a look on my codepen, https://codepen.io/jcarizon/pen/JjjaaPq

Comment: Please let me know if this is still not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: What CSS changes did you apply to fix this problem? I want learn my mistakes from this. Otherwise, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Well, the list did not overflow because you have set it to position : relative and by doing so, the div will auto height because of it. So in "#srchRslts" id, I've changed it to absolute then give a width to 93%. And to show it above other elements, I've added z-index: 10.

Comment: Please notice my changes on these elements: #srchRslts, #srchRslts li, #srchRslts li a

Comment: Oh ok. Now I see my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks also and glad it helped you :)